# How to get all TEXT outside elements in a HTML document

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath, domcrawler

I'm using Symfony DomCrawler to get all text in a document.

```
$this->crawler->filter('p')->each(function (Crawler $node, $i) {
    // process text
});
```

I'm trying to gather all text within the `<body>` that are outside of elements.

```
<body>
    This is an example
    <p>
        blablabla
    </p>
    another example
    <p>
        <span>Yo!</span>
        again, another piece of text <br/>
        with an annoy BR in the middle
    </p>
</body>
```

I'm using PHP Symfony and can use XPath (preferred) or RegEx.

Comment: I don't know about Symfony DomCrawler, but XPath for getting text node that is directly within `<body>` would be : `//body/text()` (some XPath processor doesn't support returning text node though)

Comment: Does this take into account text in nested elements?

Comment: No. If you went them as well just add another `/` : `//body//text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string value of the entire document can be obtained with this simple XPath:

```
string(/)
```

All text nodes in the document would be:

```
//text()
```

The immediate text node children of `body` would be:

```
/body/text()
```

Note that the XPaths that select text nodes would typically be converted to concatenated string values, depending upon context.